# Can I use only nvidia-drivers for host machine of docker based system?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, cuda, nvidia, nvidia-docker

I have problem understanding cuda and docker ecosystem.

On a host (ubuntu 22.04) server I want to spawn multiple Machiene Learning Jupyter notebooks.

Is it enough if I install in the host ubuntu  ONLY Nvidia drivers like this:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
DISTRIBUTION=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID | sed -e 's/\.//g')
echo $DISTRIBUTION
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/$DISTRIBUTION/x86_64/cuda-keyring_1.0-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-keyring_1.0-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda-drivers

sudo reboot

#After reboot verify if the CUDA driver is installed:
nvidia-smi
```

and then install `cuda` in containers like this:

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu2204.pin
sudo mv cuda-ubuntu2204.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64/3bf863cc.pub
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64/ /"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

I think the purest way is to install only required packages on host systems and enrich the containers with all the necessary packages. That is why I wonder if this approach is reasonable.

1. Do I understand correctly that the container will then use the drivers from host system?
2. Is installing `cuda` enough to be installed in the conatiners, or I shall install `cuda-toolkit` as it contains more additional packages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do I understand correctly that the container will then use the drivers from host system?

Yes, the container will use the drivers from the host system.  If you are building your own container, *do not install the drivers in the container*.

> Is installing cuda enough to be installed in the conatiners, or I shall install cuda-toolkit as it contains more additional packages?

You might not ever want to install `cuda` in this scenario.  You can install `cuda` (which will also install the drivers mentioned in your question 1) *in the host machine*.  That is acceptable.  In the container, if you are building it yourself, you don't want to install `cuda`, at most the `cuda-toolkit`.

> Can I use only nvidia-drivers for host machine of docker based system?

There are [generally 3 items needed](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/install-guide.html#docker) in the host machine, beyond the linux OS install, to make it ready for CUDA-enabled container usage:

1. The GPU drivers
2. A recent docker version
3. The NVIDIA container toolkit (see above link for install instructions)

It is not necessary to install the CUDA toolkit (i.e. the items beyond the GPU driver install) in the host machine.  These will usually be installed in the container if they are needed in the container.

Comment: " In the container, if you are building it yourself, you don't want to install cuda, at most the cuda-toolkit." 
So where/when to install `cuda` if not in host and not in container?

Comment: `cuda` largely consists of two parts: the GPU driver and the `cuda-toolkit`. When using containers, my suggestion is *its not necessary to install `cuda` anywhere*.  Install the GPU driver in the host machine, and the `cuda-toolkit` in the container.  When I use terms like `cuda` here and `cuda-toolkit`, I am specifically referring to the [meta-packages](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#package-manager-metas), the same way you are referring to it in your question. You can, if you wish, install `cuda` in the host machine, because it will install the drivers.

Comment: That makes it clear - thank you.